# How to make a jsp page download 2 files

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, download, response.redirect

I have a download.jsp page that when loaded, causes a file to download
using the following code:

```
String contentDisp = "attachment; filename=file_" + "."+DeptNumber+ ".txt";     
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", contentDisp);
```

After this, i do some out.write(....) statements and then in the end out.flush()
which is when the user receives a download file request from the browser.
After that i use:

```
response.sendRedirect("landingpage.jsp");
```

To move the user on to the next page.

Now, I want to do the same but instead of one file, i want the page to cause 2 files to be generated for download. I did 2 changes:

1) I changed the beginning of the jsp to check for an attribute, and according to the attribute sent, generate the correct file for download.

```
String downloadDeptNumber = request.getAttribute("dept")==null ? "1" : request.getAttribute("dept").toString();
```

and

2) In the end of the page instead of redirecting to the next page, i check if the attribute was 1, i change it to 2 and redirect to the same page. If it wasn't 1, i redirect to the end page (landing page) that i used originally with only 1 download above.

```
if (downloadDeptNumber.equals("1")) 
{
      redirectUrl="download.jsp" ;
      session.setAttribute("dept", "2");
}
else
{
      redirectUrl= "landingpage.jsp";
      session.removeAttribute("dept");
}
response.sendRedirect(redirectUrl);
```

But it seems i can't redirect to the same page i am on currently.

Does anyone have a solution for me ?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably better put both files in a zip and let user download that one.

Comment: also, sorry for using scriptlets <% %> in jsp, this is old code being maintained, new code is JSTL.

Comment: zip is not a solution for my type of users

Comment: Maybe just give user a page with two links? Or make two different pages, one for each file, and redirect between them? (That would be strange, actually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**option # 1 : separate link**

Give 2 separate link to download each file

**option #2** : zip file

make a single zip file on server using java API and download

**option #3** : Use java script

make a java script function that will open the new tab and download the each file simultaneously

Below code should run to download each file

```
window.open(
  'http://download_file_link',
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
```

Comment: went for separate links